# SwiftUI Sheet which contains ScrollView scrolls down when the ScrollView is reaching top

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview

Hey I'm making SwiftUI Bottom Sheet and wanted to put ScrollView inside of the bottom sheet view. The problem is when I scroll the scrollView, I don't want my bottom sheet to react. But whenever I scroll to the top with the scrollView I implemented inside the bottomsheet, bottom sheet starts to close.

If there's anyone who can help me with exclusively scroll the scrollview and does not affect the bottom sheet, please help!

Thank you in advance.

The code looks like below

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                Button("Show Bottom Sheet") {
                    showSheet.toggle()
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                    /// Bottom Sheet which contains scrollview in it
                    BottomSheetView()
                        .presentationDetents([.medium])
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried exclusively, simultaneous options, highPriorityGesture
but the all didn't work

Comment: show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show the code for `BottomSheetView` with the problem `ScrollView`

Comment: Your current behavior is exactly what I want to achieve. All my sheets with scrollview/list inside won't scroll the sheet when it reaches top. 
how can that be

Answer (score 0):

Apply `.interactiveDismissEnabled()` to `BottomSheetView`:

```swift
BottomSheetView()
    .presentationDetents([.medium])
    .ignoresSafeArea()
    .interactiveDismissDisabled() // <- HERE
```

Of course, you will need to provide the user with another way to dismiss the sheet instead.